# google analytics goal with dynamic funnel

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, analytics, single-page-application, react-ga

I wish to configure google analytics goal where users reaching to a specific result page after going through an extensive wizard asking them bunch of questions.

I set up a custom goal of type destination where the url equals to the result page resource, and then enable the funnel option to add the urls of each wizard question.

I'm facing 2 problems:

1. How would I configure the steps of the wizard in the funnel if the wizard is dynamic and is changing based on the answers of the user.
   For example a valid path could be `wizard/1 -> wizard/2 -> ...` and it can also be `wizard/1 -> wizard/3 -> ...` depending on the answer of the user.

   Also, users are getting a back button in the wizard to go back a question and they can also use the browser back navigation button, so eventually a user path could turn out to be `wizard/1 -> wizard/2 -> wizard/1 -> wizard/2 -> wizard/3 -> ...` all depends on how the user is navigating the wizard, so what can I do about that?
2. I can define only 20 steps in the funnel of the goal and my wizard can be 50+ questions each having their own url.

How can I resolve these issues?

**Edit:**

I've tried to setup my goal url destination as the following regex:
`\/report`
and added 1 step with url equal to `\/wizard\/\d+` in the hope that it will catch all the questions the user followed but unfortunately it only captured question in the funnel and not all of the questions. I also can't figure which question it did capture since it only say the name of the step and not the url which I gave to it the name `question`.
Here's how my goal is configured:
[image]

Here's the goal flow:
[image]

**Edit:**

I've tried to approach this by seeing the funnel from the Behavior Flow and it seems that there's a drop-off at the 5th question although this is not true and I've went through the whole wizard to see the funnel with no dropouts and yet this is the report I get:
[image]
Not sure what's going on, I'm using `react-ga` and configured every route of my app to be tracked.

Any suggestions?